# How to Make HTML Checkbox Run a Function when Created Dynamically Using D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, leaflet

[Edition] I think I found my problem. It's with my CSV being converted to JSON.  In my D3 I'm using myJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); to make my JSON.  The problem is my lat and lon are strings.  When I place the original JSON in my JavaScript everything worked with my D3 made checkboxes.  When I use the converted version, it didn't work.  So my question now is, how to convert my CSV file into objects and not strings, in my D3 and place in global JSON variable? So I need to convert the string numbers to real numbers in the conversion process (CSV to JSON).

I found a concept that works great!  Here’s the link to the jsFiddle of the example I used, https://jsfiddle.net/xf4fwwme/44/.

However, to customize this concept a bit that will work best for me, I used D3.js to create the checkboxes dynamically and to load the data from the CSV file and then JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)) the data into a global json object/variable, so I can update my checkboxes and data easier by use of a CSV file.  I managed to create the checkboxes, but I can seem to run the function like the jsfiddle example above.   It works well when I hardcode the checkbox HTML into place but when added dynamically with D3.js, I nothing works.  It seems like a no brainer, but I just can’t get it to run the function.  Below is the D3 checkbox form script I’m using.  Everything else is like the above jsfiddle example.  Any assistance to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Works perfect when I hardcode the HTML like below; like the jsfiddle example:

```
<div class="checkboxWrapper">

<div id="form">

<input type="checkbox" id="cbAdults" checked>Adults

<input type="checkbox" id="cbYouth" checked>Youth

<input type="checkbox" id="cbSeniors" checked>Seniors

<input type="checkbox" id="cbMen" checked>Men

<input type="checkbox" id="cbWomen" checked>Women
<br>

<button id="btnForm">Filter</button>

</div>
</div>
```

It won’t work this way.  The checkboxes and data are loaded dynamically using D3.js.

```js
var myJSON;

d3.csv("data/checkboxData.csv", function(error, data) {
  if (error) {
    alert("Data didn't load, Refresh your browser");
  } else {
    myJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data)); //convert CSV data to JSON and load in Global variable

    var selectBox = d3.select("#form")
      .selectAll("input")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("label")
      .append("input")
      .attr("checked", true)
      .attr("type", "checkbox")
      .attr("id", function(d, i) {
        return d.cbID;
      })
      .attr("onClick", filter()) ////can't get this to run the function
    .on('change', filter()) /////and I can't get this to run the function
    .attr("for", function(d, i) {
      return i;
    });

    d3.selectAll("#form label")
      .data(data)
      .attr("class", "checkbox")
      .append("text").text(function(d) {
        return " " + d.checkBoxValue
      })
  }
});

let myMarkers = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);
btnForm.onclick = () => filter();

filter();


function filter() {
  myMarkers.clearLayers();

  let myJSONcopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(myJSON));

  let categories = [];

  if (cbAdults.checked) {
    categories.push('adults');
  }
  if (cbYouth.checked) {
    categories.push('youth');
  }
  if (cbSeniors.checked) {
    categories.push('seniors')
  }
  if (cbMen.checked) {
    categories.push('men');
  }
  if (cbWomen.checked) {
    categories.push('women');
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < myJSONcopy.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < categories.length; j++) {
      for (let k = 0; k < myJSONcopy[i].demographic.length; k++)
        if (categories[j] == myJSONcopy[i].demographic[k] &&
          !myJSONcopy[i].added) {

          L.circleMarker([myJSONcopy[i].lat, myJSONcopy[i].lon], {
            color: myJSONcopy[i].color,
            fillColor: myJSONcopy[i].color,
            fillOpacity: 1,
            radius: 10.0
          }).addTo(myMarkers);

          myJSONcopy[i].added = true;

          ///Fit to bounds
          map.fitBounds(myMarkers.getBounds(), {
            padding: [150, 150],
            animate: true,
            duration: 2
          });
          break;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkboxWrapper">
  <div id="form"></div>
  <br>
  <button id="btnForm">Filter</button>
</div>
```

Comment: use event delegation instead of event attributes.

Comment: Can you explain a little what event delegation mean/is.  I apologize for my lack of understanding.

Comment: @TonyT  have you defined myMarkers in your code (but not posted it?)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to post it. But I edited my original post to show it.  The missing line I added:  let myMarkers = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);